# How to restrict user based on ip address in openldap

Tags: linux, ubuntu, centos, ldap, openldap

In organization we have setup ldap using openldap, i access it with GUI phpldapadmin.

**we have one requirement to allow access some user from specific IPAddress.**

I searched but still not able to get the exact solution.

example.ldif

dn: cn=xyz,ou=Person,dc=example,dc=com

cn: xyz

gidnumber: 570

homedirectory: /home/users/xyz

iphostnumber: 10.10.0.0

loginshell: /sbin/nologin

mail: xyz@example.com

objectclass: inetOrgPerson

objectclass: posixAccount

objectclass: top

objectclass: ipHost

postaladdress: 123xyz

sn: XYZ

uid: xyz

uidnumber: 1012

so we want xyz user should able to access openldap from iphostnumber: 10.10.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by creating appropriate ACLs in your directory. Take a look at [this forum thread](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200803/msg00235.html) in which the OP wants to have an IP address-based (and also filter based) access control to the directory. There are [examples for IP-based ACLs](http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200803/msg00237.html) which might help you. Perhaps, something like this:

```
access to *
       by peername.ip=10.10.0.0 read
       by * none
```

Of course, don't forget to read the OpenLDAP [slapd.access](https://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/access-control.html) manual.

Comment: Thanks...after reading slapd.access manual it is more clear how to do restriction on openldap.